# Image floating right that is further in HTML structure than text in paragraphs

Tags: html, css, position, css-float

If I place an image before the text, I just need to set the image width, `float: right` and the text nicely wraps around it.

But when I put image after the text, it floats right but under the paragraphs. I tried to place all paragraphs in div and set the width, but if I do so, the image is next to the text and the text doesn't wrap around it.

```
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>

<img src="">
```

Is there any way to make this image float correctly if it is placed lower in the HTML structure ?

### EDIT :

I want it to look like this: https://jsfiddle.net/yn10xoLz/  
And the problem is, how to achive the same thing, but when image is under the text in HTML structure. I tried one of the answears, but it doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/kr7ey1r2/

Comment: I think just the way the html loads, you can't have the img load after the text and then try to make the text wrap under the image. The best you could do is create 2 columns. https://jsfiddle.net/3467cwma/

Answer (score 1):

This does what you are looking for, it's a bit `unconventional` but works ;)

[Codepan](http://codepen.io/creativenauts/pen/BzQOma)

Comment: Emirhan Özlen also had in his answear "display: inline-block" but it didn't work. https://jsfiddle.net/kr7ey1r2/2/

Comment: yes, i see now. Give me a few minutes, I'll provide you an unconventional method using :before / :after pseudo class.

Comment: So there's no hope ? :/

Comment: I don't think so, I got held up at work so didn't have much time to try my idea. I'll see what I can whip up real quick.

Comment: Here, this is a bit unconventional and of course is just a simple starting point but it does what you are looking for ;)

http://codepen.io/creativenauts/pen/BzQOma

Comment: Nice ! But what kind of HTML is that by the way ?

Comment: if you are speaking about the HTML in the codepen, i'm just using jade markdown language. I use it in all of my projects, speeds up workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Set the paragraph as float:left

Comment: It doesn't work. I think it's becaouse paragraphs doesn't have any width set. But if i set width, they doesn't wrap around image anymore.

Comment: you're right, you need to set an height to your last paragraph (and keep the float:left)

Comment: I don't understand. How setting height would help ? Also check out my edit, i added links to two jsfiddles.

Comment: the jsfiddle from @Emirhan Özlen seems working
[the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fkp8d/894/)

Comment: No it's not. Just paste some long text in place of a, b and c: http://jsfiddle.net/fkp8d/896/

Comment: So use the height, use js to get it, not available right now to do this in jsfiddle

Comment: Can you post some jsfiddle ? I don't really get what do you mean.

Comment: As soon as possible

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kr7ey1r2/3/
height doesn't matter anymore, just use width
Or you can also organize in a table
`<table>
<tr>
<td>paragraph</td><td>image</td>
</tr>
</table>`

Comment: As i said, i tried to put paragraphs in div and set it's width, but when you do so, the text doesn't wrap around image. Its just a column of text now. I want it to look like this: https://jsfiddle.net/yn10xoLz/

Comment: Ahah the image before is way more simple :D, why do you need the image after ?

Comment: Because i want text to wrap around image on desktop and then with media queries i want to display that image under the text on mobile

Answer (score 0):

Your questions looks like you are trying to do things in a wrong way in both cases.

**Question 1** - Is there any way to make this image float correctly if it is placed lower in the HTML structure ?

Answer is **No**, placing it above is the only proper way to make it float correctly.

**Question 2** - If not, is there any way to show image UNDER the text, if it's placed BEFORE text in the HTML structure ?

Answer is **No**, if you don't want to add absolute position to images. Because absolutely positioned element can be anywhere (above, below or ..)

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: As i said, i can't set width, becaouse text won't wrap around like this: https://jsfiddle.net/yn10xoLz/

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your paragraphs and images are all set to float left. If you're trying to do this multiple times in one page then you'll need to put them in a containing div.

```
.paragraph {
  float: left;
}
.image {
  float: right;
}
.exampleDiv {
  width:100%;
  float: left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ad9qdyya/1/

Comment: I tried it, but it seems it doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/kr7ey1r2/

Answer (score 0):

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fkp8d/894/)

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="center">
    <p>a</p>
    <p>b</p>
    <p>c</p>
  </div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="right">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap {
  text-align: center;
}

.center,
.right {
  display: inline-block;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
```